# Adding text to a PDF document with itextsharp

Tags: itext

Is it possible to add text to end of a PDF document created by a software other that itextsharp by using itextsharp? I need to add signatures to hundreds of PDF documents so I am looking for a way to do this automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Provided you have access rights to modify the PDFs.  If they are password protected and you have the password you can use itextsharp to open them with the password to be able to edit them.

You can then use the itextsharp `PdfStamper` class in combination with the `PdfContentByte` class to add content to any position on the PDF.